# On Mouse Over change to Image

Tags: html

Is there a way to change the mouse into an image on `mouseover` over an image?

```
<a class="menu_links" onclick="displayData(11,1,0,'A')" onmouseover=""> A </a>
```

```
onmouseover="cursor: hand (a pointing hand)"
```

Comment: `img {cursor: pointer;}`

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  }
a:hover{
  cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/images10/cur918.png), auto;
  }
```

```html
<a class="menu_links" onclick="displayData(11,1,0,'A')"> Hover </a>
```

Comment: Hi sorry but this does not help me. Thank you though. I was trying to change the cursor into a image once it mouse-over to an image.

Comment: not sure if i am getting you correctly. you can replace the anchor with an image & the same will work for you